Bayes Risk for multi class classification problem
Suppose there are $K$ classes with densities $f_1, f_2,....,f_K$ and priors $\pi_1, \pi_2,....,\pi_K$ respectively. We know that the Bayes rule is given by $$\delta(x)=\underset{i=1,....,K}{\text{argmax}} \ \pi_if_i(x)$$. Show that the Bayes risk is always smaller than the lowest prior.
$$$$For $K=2$ the Bayes Risk equals $$\pi_1\int_{R_2(\delta)}f_1(x)dx+\pi_2\int_{R_1(\delta)}f_2(x)dx=\pi_1[\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(x)dx-\int_{R_1(\delta)}f_1(x)dx]+\pi_2\int_{R_1(\delta)}f_2(x)dx \\=\pi_1+\int_{R_1(\delta)}(\pi_2f_2(x)-\pi_1f_1(x))dx$$. Where $R_i(\delta)=\{x:\delta(x)=i\}, i=1, 2$ and $\delta$ is the Bayes Rule. Similarly, the Bayes Risk also equals $$\pi_2+\int_{R_2(\delta)}(\pi_1f_1(x)-\pi_2f_2(x))dx$$. Now we know that for a two class classification problem $$R_1(\delta)=\{x:\pi_1f_1(x)>\pi_2f_2(x)\} \\ R_2(\delta)=\{x:\pi_2f_2(x)>\pi_1f_1(x)\}$$ for a Bayes rule $\delta$. So the Bayes risk is less than or equal to $\text{min}(\pi_1, \pi_2)$.
$$$$But how to show this for a multi class problem I don't Know?
